# python how to detect if type is 'datetime.time'

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, typechecking

I am trying to do test to see if a data type is 'datetime.time' and if so convert it to 'datetime.datetime'.  My code snippet is below.  x_values is a series and each element of the series is a 'datetime.time'.

```
                ...
                x_values = x.loc[:, "processed_time"]
                print(x_values.dtypes)
                print(type(x_values.iloc[0]))
                print(x_values)
                if isinstance(x_values.iloc[0], datetime.time):
                    x_values = pd.to_datetime(x_values, format='%H:%M:%S')
                ...
```

But the program errors out at the test with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../risk_calculations.py", line 282, in plot_risk
    if isinstance(x_values.iloc[0], datetime.time):
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
object
<class 'datetime.time'>
1387    00:55:14
1388    10:02:01
1389    10:02:02
1390    10:02:02
1391    10:02:08
          ...   
6417    14:36:49
6418    14:36:51
6419    15:24:52
6420    15:36:59
6422    16:21:03
Name: processed_time, Length: 3621, dtype: object
```

This Stack [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991948/detect-if-a-variable-is-a-datetime-object) seemed closest to addressing my challenge but I think I have implemented the suggestion correctly.  Note that the print statements show that the type is in fact a 'class datetime.time' as required (I think) by 'is instance' so I don't understand why the errors.  I know I can make it work if I replace the 'if' statement with:

```
if 'datetime.time' in str(type(x_values.iloc[0])):
     ...
```

But that seems kludgy.  Is there a more correct test for an instance of 'datetime.time'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-a-python-variables-type Hope this helps!

Comment: Not really.  In my question I posted the Stack answer closest to my question.  I have a workaround and I know how to get the type.  I want to know why 'isinstance()' is not working as expected or if my workaround is really the only way of checking (specifically) the 'datetime' type.